# Combining multiple json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Very new in this field and English is not my mother language. Sorry for those in advance.

Trying to use open data and the format is json.

For example,

http://data.com/openapi/sample/json/1/5?RECIPE_NM=pasta (RECIPE_NM is necessary parameter!)

this json data has

```
{  
   "Grid_20150827000000000226_1":{  
      "totalCnt":1,
      "startRow":1,
      "endRow":5,
      "result":{  
         "code":"INFO-000",
         "message":"Normal"
      },
      "row":[  
         {  
            "ROW_NUM":1,
            "RECIPE_ID":1,
            "RECIPE_NM_KO":"Pasta",
            "SUMRY":"Pasta recipe",
            "NATION_CODE":"3020001",
            "NATION_NM":"Italian",
            "TY_CODE":"3010001",
            "TY_NM":"Noodle",
            "COOKING_TIME":"10min",
            "CALORIE":"580Kcal"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

http://data.com/openapi/sample/json/1/5?RECIPE_NM=sushi

this one has

```
{  
   "Grid_20150827000000000226_1":{  
      "totalCnt":1,
      "startRow":1,
      "endRow":5,
      "result":{  
         "code":"INFO-000",
         "message":"Normal"
      },
      "row":[  
         {  
            "ROW_NUM":1,
            "RECIPE_ID":2,
            "RECIPE_NM_KO":"Sushi",
            "SUMRY":"Sushi is yummy",
            "NATION_CODE":"3020001",
            "NATION_NM":"Japanese",
            "TY_CODE":"3010001",
            "TY_NM":"rice",
            "COOKING_TIME":"30min",
            "CALORIE":"338Kcal"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Each page has different json data and I'd like to filter data by NATION_NM or RECIPE_NM_KO. To achieve this, I'm trying to combine all those recipes in one json file. How do I do this? Or Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @Mistalis I'm using Javascript

Comment: `recipes.push(data);`

Comment: @SamAxe Can you give me more details?